# Python Equivalent of a CURL Command

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to do this with a Python script:

> curl -X POST -d '{"username": "user","password": "password","scopes": ["download"]}' https://api.fakedomain.com/v2.0/oauth/token

When I execute this from a linux command line, it outputs a client access token.   I am trying to make this work through a Python script.  I have tried the following:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.fakedomain.com/v2.0/oauth/token'
creds = {"username": "<user>",
     "password": "<password>",
     "scopes": ["download"]}
r = requests.post(url, data=creds)
print(r.text)
```

The script completes with exit code 0, but I can't find the access token anywhere.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `json` keyword instead of `data`?

My requests code looks like this:

```
import requests
url = 'https://fake-website.com/token'
data = {'key': 'val'}
requests.post(url, json=data)
```

Comment: You nailed it!  That worked, thank you so much!  I have to wait a few minutes to award it to you.  You're too fast!

Answer (score 0):

For conversions of CURL commands to Python code you also can use [this web app](https://curl.trillworks.com/).

It generates:

```
import requests
data = '{"username": "user","password": "password","scopes": ["download"]}'
response = requests.post('https://api.fakedomain.com/v2.0/oauth/token', data=data)
```